# gdal_translate cannot convert MSG3 channels to TIFF

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate

following this guide http://www.gdal.org/frmt_msg.html I want to convert my MSG3 HRIT format files in TIFF but I get this error

```
gdal_translate H-00 0-MSG3__-MSG3________-IR_097___-000008___-201410281200-C_ gg.tif
ERROR 4: `H-000-MSG3__-MSG3________-IR_097___-000008___-201410281200-C_' not recognised as a supported file format.
GDALOpen failed - 4
`H-000-MSG3__-MSG3________-IR_097___-000008___-201410281200-C_' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

The same error I have on windows.

Can you help me?

Comment: Perhaps your GDAL is not built with MSG driver. Try ´gdalinfo --format MSG´ and read the response.

Comment: At least OSGEO4W and gisinternals builds of GDAL do **not** include the MSG driver.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the filename has a space in it, and the two parts of the filename are being intepreted as two arguments. This isn't really a GDAL problem, but rather how shells work.

Try adding a quote around the filename, or just rename the file.

Comment: May be, but space in `H-00 0´ gives a different error message for me on Windows: FAILURE: Too many command options.

Comment: OK, exactly what do you think the input filename is? What does `gdalinfo` for that filename (in quotes) show?

Comment: My test was `rename test.tif "H-00 0-MSG3__-MSG3________-IR_097___-000
008___-201410281200-C_"` and `gdalinfo  "H-00 0-MSG3__-MSG3________-IR_097___-000008___-2014102
81200-C_"`. Gdalinfo gives normal report from the renamed tiff. But by reading http://www.gdal.org/frmt_msg.html there should not be any space in `H-00 0` Obviously this format has a fixed pattern for filenames.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed your comment with the OP.